# Unable to connect to the IBM DS3524 from DS Storage Manager

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, ibm

Please don't mind me, I am new to IBM storage.

I need to connect to IBM DS Storage 3524 by using default IP from each controller Ethernet ports.

**Default IPs**

```
Controller A, Port 1 = 192.168.128.101
Controller B, Port 1 = 192.168.128.102
```

I plug the end of RJ45 cable from each controller to Normal Network Switch (TP-Link)

I have **DS Storage Manager 10** installed on desktop computer with static IP `192.168.128.10`.

I can ping to both controller IPs as image below:

[image: PING to both Controller IPs]

I tried to use auto scan subsystem on Storage Manager, didn't work.

So I manually add Subsystem by using out-of-band type, and I get error as below:

[image: Error Message while manually adding]

Question

1. How can I add the Storage DS3524 to DS Storage Manager?
2. Do I need to use special switch, SAN Switch or FC Switch?

Comment: Your pings show the same IP - not 1 separate IPs. You are pinging Controller B only from your screen cap. There is no special switching needed, just need to be able to contact both controllers.

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the wrong photo, I am sure I can PING to both IP: `192.168.128.101` and `192.168.128.102`.

Comment: Any yellow or red lights on either of the controllers?  Can you access either controller via `ssh`?

Comment: I don't see any red or yellow light. I see all green lights.

Comment: sorry for `ssh`, I haven't tested yet. would you mind to guide me how to connect through `ssh` or any other way. thanks.

Comment: Do both controllers have the latest firmware? I had this happen last year and a firmware update resolved it.

Comment: I think the firmware is out-of-date. Could you advice me how to upgrade firmware? as you can see in the 2nd Image, I tried to upgrade firmware with **Firmware Upgrade Tool.** but have the error as the message.

Comment: You can use out-of-band connections to upgrade firmware. These are the second ports on the controllers. I don't recall what the ips are set to by default. Keep n mind that you cannot jump firmware versions, you have to go from the installed version to the next release and so on.  If you controller is fried and you don't have an ibm service contract, you can find them on eBay.

Comment: I have tried to upgrade the Storage Manager Version. now I can use auto scan to search for IBM Storage SubSystem. but it show **Unresponsive** Status because of controller B. I have tried some troubleshooting but not still cannot launch Subsystem Mangement Windows. Any advice so far?